# Exactly why coefficient of $x^ky^{n-k}$ is $C(k,n)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

in combination when we have a binomial lattices like $(x+y)^n$ the coefficient of $x^ky^{n-k}$ is equal with $C(k,n)$ ...  for example we have $(x+y)^4$ so we have this $4$ factor $(x+y)(x+y)(x+y)(x+y)$ and we want to find the coefficient of $x^2y^2$ ? 
**I want a complete answer thanks !!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The coefficient of $x^{k}y^{n-k}$ in the expansion of $(x+y)^n=(x+y)(x+y)\cdots(x+y)$ is the number of ways we can select $x$ from $k$ of the factors and $y$ from the remaining $n-k$ factors.  There are $C(n,k)$ ways to select $k$ factors out of the $n$ factors from which to take an $x$, so this gives the coefficient of $x^{k}y^{n-k}$.

Comment: thanks ... and i know this too ! can you explain why we can select x from k of the factors ? for ex ... $x^2 can be selected from fact 1,2 or 1,3 or 1,4 or 2,3 or 2,4 or 3,4 so we have 6 state ! i want to know the relation between combination and power in this case ! thanks

Comment: as an example, $(x+y)^3=(x+y)(x+y)(x+y)=xxx+{xxy}+{xyx}+xyy+{yxx}+yxy+yyx+yyy$, so the coefficient of $x^2y$ is $C(3,2)$ since this gives the number of terms that have 2 factors of x (and 1 factor of y).

Comment: thanks ... xxx+xxy+xyx+xyy+yxx+yxy+yyx+yyy was helpful ! so can we say for $$x^2y$$ we have 3 Combinations xxy xyx and yxx ! and for ex for $$x^2y^2$$ all the Combinations for 'xxyy'? that is 4!/2!2! = 6 ?

Comment: @bluebird7 Yes, that's right -- the number of ways to get $x^2 y^2$ in the expansion of $(x+y)^4$ by this reasoning is just $C(4,2)=\frac{4!}{2!2!}=6$, given by xxyy, xyxy, xyyx, yxxy, yxyx, yyxx.

Comment: do you know ? i understand the C(4,2) but conceptually its Permutation of 2 same x and 2 same y that it will be 4!/2!2! !

Comment: @bluebird7 That's right, $C(n,k)$ can also be interpreted as the number of permutations of $n$ objects, where $k$ of them are of type 1 and $n-k$ of them are of type 2.

Answer (score 1):

Since,

$$(x+y)^n = \sum_{j=0}^n {n \choose j}x^{n-j}y^j$$

For $n=4$, such us $(x+y)^4$, $x^2y^2$ is obtained by matching pattern in $x^{n-j}y^j$. In $x^2y^2$, we know $j = 2$ and $2 = n-j = 4-2$. Using the equation above,

$${n \choose j}x^{n-j}y^j$$
$$={4 \choose 2}x^{4-2}y^2$$
$$={4 \choose 2}x^{2}y^2$$
$$=6x^2y^2$$

Comment: any body know this .... so why 6 ? i want a complete description !

Comment: jeez. ${4 \choose 2} = \dfrac{4!}{2!(4-2)!} = 6$

Comment: dear joey ! i know this ,... i want a conceptual description ! about the relation between power and combination !

Answer (score 0):

conceptually its Permutation of 2 same x and 2 same y ... that those are :  $$xxyy-xyxy-xyyx-yyxx-yxyx-yxxy $$  that it will be :  $$4!/2!2!$$